# Sharepoint Services - List - Create view items created by {who ever logged in}

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I have list where users can see all items, but only edit items they created.

Is there a way I can create a 'Created by {User}' view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I just need to create a filter on 'created by' equals to [Me]